# Why Don't Long Text Files Work in Spyder?

Tags: python, python-3.x, spyder

I am working on a program that needs a long text file (a keypad cipher decoder) and I am working with Spyder. It says that the memory at a certain location can not be retrieved. I have tried putting the text file and the program in the same folder. Is this a problem with spyder itself or one with my code? For context, the .txt file has about 500,000 characters (100,000 most common words).

```
with open("wiki-100k.txt") as word_file:
    english_words = set(word.strip().lower() for word in word_file)

def IsWord(word):
    return word.lower() in english_words

print(IsWord("HaMs"))
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\eirta\Desktop\Ciphers\Keypad.py", line 3, in <module>
    english_words = set(word.strip().lower() for word in word_file)

  File "C:\Users\eirta\Desktop\Ciphers\Keypad.py", line 3, in <genexpr>
    english_words = set(word.strip().lower() for word in word_file)

  File "C:\Users\eirta\anaconda3\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]

UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 2814: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: Please post the error that you are getting

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\eirta\Desktop\Ciphers\untitled0.py", line 10, in <module>
    print(f.read(617215))

  File "C:\Users\eirta\anaconda3\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]

UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 617214: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: Please add it to your answer using appropriate formatting

Comment: I just did that now.

Comment: The line referenced in your error `print(f.read(617215))` is not in your code that you posted

Comment: Whoops! I had another program to try and debug it.

Comment: What is the encoding of the file? Are you sure? Are you really sure? Then use it as a parameter for [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open).

Comment: The error indicates that you have some character in your file (at byte 2814) that can't be decoded with the default encoding for your system ([CP-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252)).

Comment: Thank you for the information! It worked!